# What are the popular algorithms or softwares used in identifying or track flights by ATC?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aircraft-systems, software

Just curious to know about the algorithms /software used by ATC for tracking flights in real time.Can it be classified under ERP ?If no under which category does that fall ?

Comment: Why would you need an algorithm to track a flight? Scheduling them, routing them maybe, but tracking them?

Comment: @RonBeyer If for no other reason than combining or fusing radar tracks from multiple sites. There are different algorithms in using with different pros and cons.

Comment: True, although with Nexgen track fusion is going to become less common. The aircraft are self-reporting with high accuracy GPS positions, track and heading, etc.

Comment: ARTAS. http://www.eurocontrol.int/artas

Comment: Software-wise, the big firms of the ATC industry such as [Thales](https://www.thalesgroup.com/en/australia/what-we-do-aerospace-air-traffic-management-our-products/topsky-atm-solutions), or [Indra](http://www.indracompany.com/en/air-traffic-control-automation-system) have systems installed for a lot of ANSP, that enable ATCO to perform their duty. But the entire system needs a lot more than just a software or a few algorithm, since it connects radars, database and telecommunication elements.

Comment: @RonBeyer Any computer program is an implementation of some algorithm.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? Algorithms/software is broad and ATC is using a trackload of software for many things. So it's even broader. Are you looking for how flight data are processed? How data are displayed? Please specify otherwise I'm afraid the question will be closed as "too broad" or even "off topic"

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm not sure I (2 years ago) said anything about what an algorithm is, only questioned why they would need one in this context... I'm a a professional software developer myself...

Comment: @RonBeyer You need an algorithm because, if a computer does it, it does it with an algorithm. Even if it's a boring, obvious algorithm that doesn't have a name -- "Loop through the list of radar contacts and plot them on the screen" is an algorithm. Anyway, not a big deal.